# How can I speed up the processing of the received channel socket

Tags: c#, async-await, socket

This currently runs with 1400+ sockets and manages data correctly and in the manner the application requires. I do have an issue with the `HandleData` method where the receive channel stacks an excess of messages. They eventually all get processed the channel rarely exceeds 250 items.

Besides the obvious of using an off the shelf socket class, I have a few questions about my implementation.

- How can I speed up the processing of the received channel?
- Are there any glaring issues with the code (code smells) or potential improvements?
- Is the `async/await task` implemented correctly?
- Would it be better to use a `BlockingCollection` instead of `Channel` for the `_receive` messages?

Logger:

```
using Serilog;

public static class Logger
{
    public static ILogger Create(string name)
    {
        return Log.Logger.ForContext("SourceContext", name);
    }
}
```

SocketOptions:

```
using System;

public class SocketOptions
{
    public int ReceiveBufferSize { get; set; } = 1024;

    public int SendBufferSize { get; set; } = 1024;

    public bool AutoReconnect { get; set; } = false;

    public TimeSpan AutoReconnectDelay { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

    public int AutoReconnectAttempts { get; set; } = 10;
}
```

ISocket:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public interface ISocket : IDisposable
{
    void Add(ISocketListener listener);

    Task CloseAsync();

    Task<bool> ConnectAsync();

    void Remove(ISocketListener listener);

    void Send(string data);
}
```

ISocketListener:

```
using System;

public interface ISocketListener
{
    void OnConnected(Socket socket);

    void OnData(dynamic data);

    void OnDisconnected(Socket socket);

    void OnError(Socket socket, Exception e);
}
```

Socket: (Updated with aepot suggestions)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Channels;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Core.Utils;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Serilog;

public class Socket : ISocket
{
    private readonly string _endpoint;

    private readonly IList<ISocketListener> _listeners =
        new List<ISocketListener>();

    private readonly ILogger _logger =
        Logger.Create(nameof(Socket));

    private readonly SocketOptions _options;

    private readonly Channel<string> _receive =
        Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>(
            new UnboundedChannelOptions
            {
                SingleReader = true,
                SingleWriter = true
            });

    private readonly Channel<string> _send =
        Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>(
            new UnboundedChannelOptions
            {
                SingleReader = true,
                SingleWriter = false
            });

    private CancellationTokenSource _stopping;
    
    private int _count;

    private ClientWebSocket _socket;

    private bool _disposed;

    public Socket(string endpoint, SocketOptions options)
    {
        _endpoint = endpoint;
        _options = options;
    }

    public bool IsConnected => _socket?.State == WebSocketState.Open;

    private readonly AutoResetEvent _wait = new (true);

    public async Task<bool> ConnectAsync()
    {
        _wait.WaitOne();
        
        try
        {
            if (IsConnected)
            {
                return IsConnected;
            }

            if (_socket?.State != WebSocketState.None)
            {
                _socket = new ClientWebSocket
                {
                    Options =
                    {
                        KeepAliveInterval = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan
                    }
                };
            }

            _stopping ??= new CancellationTokenSource();

            var token = _stopping.Token;

            await _socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(_endpoint), token);

            if (IsConnected)
            {
                _ = RunTasks(token);

                HandleConnected();
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            /* Ignore */
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Error(e, $"Error connecting: {_endpoint}");

            HandleError(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            _wait.Set();
        }

        return IsConnected;
    }

    public async Task CloseAsync()
    {
        _logger.Information($"Closed: {_endpoint}");

        try
        {
            if (IsConnected)
            {
                await _socket
                    .CloseAsync(
                        WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure,
                        string.Empty,
                        CancellationToken.None)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            _stopping?.Cancel();
        }
        finally
        {
            _socket.Dispose();

            _stopping?.Dispose();
            _stopping = null;
        }

        HandleDisconnected();
    }

    public void Send(string data)
    {
        _send.Writer.TryWrite(data);
    }

    public void Add(ISocketListener listener)
    {
        lock (_listeners)
        {
            if (!_listeners.Contains(listener))
            {
                _listeners.Add(listener);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Remove(ISocketListener listener)
    {
        lock (_listeners)
        {
            if (_listeners.Contains(listener))
            {
                _listeners.Remove(listener);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(_disposed = true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            try
            {
                _stopping?.Cancel();
            }
            catch
            {
                /* Ignore */
            }

            _stopping?.Dispose();
            _socket?.Dispose();
            _wait.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void HandleConnected()
    {
        ISocketListener[] listeners;

        lock (_listeners)
        {
            listeners = _listeners.ToArray();
        }

        foreach (var listener in listeners)
        {
            listener.OnConnected(this);
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleDataAsync(string item)
    {
        await Task
            .Run(() =>
            {
                var data = JsonConvert
                    .DeserializeObject<dynamic>(item);

                ISocketListener[] listeners;

                lock (_listeners)
                {
                    listeners = _listeners.ToArray();
                }

                foreach (var listener in listeners)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        listener.OnData(data);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        _logger.Error(e, "Error invoking listener");
                    }
                }
            })
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private void HandleDisconnected()
    {
        ISocketListener[] listeners;

        lock (_listeners)
        {
            listeners = _listeners.ToArray();
        }

        foreach (var listener in listeners)
        {
            listener.OnDisconnected(this);
        }
    }

    private void HandleError(Exception e)
    {
        ISocketListener[] listeners;

        lock (_listeners)
        {
            listeners = _listeners.ToArray();
        }

        foreach (var listener in listeners)
        {
            listener.OnError(this, e);
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessDataAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            var reader = _receive.Reader;

            while (await reader.WaitToReadAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                if (reader.TryRead(out var item))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await HandleDataAsync(item);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        _logger.Error(e, "Error handling data");

                        HandleError(e);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Interlocked.Decrement(ref _count);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            /* Ignore */
        }
    }

    private async Task ReceiveAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            await using var stream = new MemoryStream();

            var buffer = new Memory<byte>(new byte[_options.ReceiveBufferSize]);

            var read = 0;

            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if (!IsConnected)
                {
                    break;
                }

                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                ValueWebSocketReceiveResult result;
                do
                {
                    result = await _socket
                        .ReceiveAsync(buffer, token)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);

                    if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (buffer.Length > 0)
                    {
                        await stream
                            .WriteAsync(buffer.Slice(0, result.Count), token)
                            .ConfigureAwait(false);

                        read += result.Count;
                    }
                } while (!result.EndOfMessage);

                var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, read);

                read = 0;
                
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);

                if (_count > 250)
                {
                    _logger.Warning($"Channel: {_count} items");
                }

                _receive.Writer.TryWrite(data);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            /* Ignore */
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Error(e, "Error receiving data");

            HandleError(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            await CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (_options.AutoReconnect)
            {
                await ReconnectAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessSendAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            var reader = _send.Reader;

            while (await reader.WaitToReadAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                if (_socket.State != WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (reader.TryRead(out var item))
                {
                    var data = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item));

                    await _socket
                        .SendAsync(data, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, token)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            /* Ignore */
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Error(e, "Error sending data");

            HandleError(e);
        }
    }

    private async Task ReconnectAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            var count = 0;

            while (!_disposed)
            {
                if (_options.AutoReconnectAttempts <= 0 ||
                    _options.AutoReconnectAttempts <= count)
                {
                    _logger.Warning("Reconnect attempts exceeded");

                    break;
                }

                _logger.Information($"Attempting reconnect: {_endpoint}");
                
                if (await ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    break;
                }

                count++;

                await Task
                    .Delay(_options.AutoReconnectDelay, token)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            /* Ignore */
        }
    }

    private async Task RunTasks(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await Task
            .WhenAll(
                ReceiveAsync(token),
                ProcessSendAsync(token),
                ProcessDataAsync(token)
            )
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

SocketListener Implementation:

```
public class CoinbaseCandleListener : ISocketListener
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger =
        Logger.Create(nameof(Coinbase));

    private readonly List<CandleConsolidator> _consolidators = 
        new ();

    public CoinbaseCandleListener(Symbol symbol)
    {
        Symbol = symbol;
    }

    public Symbol Symbol { get; }

    public void OnConnected(Socket socket)
    {
        _logger.Information($"Connected: {Symbol.Name}");

        Subscribe(socket);
    }

    public void OnData(dynamic data)
    {
        if (data.type != "match" ||
            data.type != "last_match")
        {
            return;
        }

        var time = (DateTime) data.time;
        var price = (double) data.price;
        var size = (double) data.size;

        foreach (var consolidator in _consolidators)
        {
            consolidator.Process(time, price, size);
        }
    }

    public void OnDisconnected(Socket socket)
    {
        _logger.Information($"Disconnected: {Symbol.Name}");
    }

    public void OnError(Socket socket, Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Error(e, $"Error: {Symbol.Name}");
    }

    public void Add(CandleConsolidator consolidator)
    {
        _consolidators.Add(consolidator);
    }

    private void Subscribe(Socket socket)
    {
        var name = $"{Symbol.Base}-{Symbol.Quote}";

        var data = new
        {
            type = "subscribe",
            product_ids = new[]
            {
                name
            },
            channels = new[]
            {
                "matches"
            }
        };

        socket.Send(
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
    }

    private void Unsubscribe(Socket socket)
    {
        var name = $"{Symbol.Base}-{Symbol.Quote}";

        var data = new
        {
            type = "unsubscribe",
            product_ids = new[]
            {
                name
            },
            channels = new[]
            {
                "matches"
            }
        };

        socket.Send(
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
    }
}
```

CandleConsolidator:

```
public class CandleConsolidator : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger = 
        Logger.Create(nameof(CandleConsolidator));

    private readonly Action<Candle> _action;
    private readonly IntervalType _interval;

    private readonly SemaphoreQueue _sync = new(1, 1);

    public CandleConsolidator(IntervalType interval, Action<Candle> action)
    {
        _interval = interval;
        _action = action;
    }

    public Candle Current { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _sync?.Dispose();
    }
    
    public async void Process(DateTime time, double price, double size)
    {
        var open = time
            .RoundTo(_interval)
            .Subtract(_interval.ToTimeSpan());

        Candle updated;

        try
        {
            await _sync.WaitAsync();
            
            if (Current?.OpenTime != open)
            {
                if (Current != null)
                {
                    var closed = Current;
                    closed.IsClosed = true;

                    // TODO: Move this outside of _sync
                    _action.Invoke(closed);
                }

                Current = new Candle
                {
                    OpenTime = open,
                    Open = price,
                    High = price,
                    Low = price,
                    Close = price,
                    Volume = size
                };
            }
            else
            {
                Current.High = Math.Max(Current.High, price);
                Current.Low = Math.Min(Current.Low, price);
                Current.Close = price;
                Current.Volume += size;
            }

            updated = Current;
        }
        finally
        {
            _sync.Release();
        }

        _action.Invoke(updated);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've looked at the continuations mixed with `async` and I do agree and have changed that. The socket does implement `IDisposable` which is on the `ISocket` interface. I've made the `HandleData` `async` and awaitable now as if one exception was thrown on the `ISocketListener` all other listeners would not receive data - fixed with try catch. This is using the producer consumer pattern, the `Socket` is the producer and the `ISocketListener` is the consumer, I'm just not using RX. `Span<T>` and `Memory<T>` are new to me, looking into them now. Thanks for the feedback, it's much appreciated!

Comment: `async Task SomeMethod() { await SomeInnerMethod(); }` can be optimized as `Task SomeMethod() { return SomeInnerMethod(); }`. It eliminates redundant State Machine which is somewhat good for performance. The optimization is applicable 1) only with single `await` per method, 2) only if it's the last statement, 3) `await` is not inside `try-catch` or `using` block. _Please don't edit the code anymore because someone probably is writing review at the moment. Review for not actual code is not helpful._ I removed my previous comment as it's not actual.

Comment: @AdamH Please amend your question and include everything which is not built-in, like `ISocket`, `ISocketListener`, `SocketOptions`, etc. Please also amend your existing code to be able compile it. For example, this is not a valid C# code `private readonly AutoResetEvent _wait = new(true);`

Comment: Please add the using statements at the top of the file.

Comment: @PeterCsala I'm using .NET 5.0, in C# 9.0 this is valid syntax `private readonly AutoResetEvent _wait = new(true);` I have updated to include everything referenced.

Comment: Why would I assume a problem in the [code presented in revision 4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/254521/4) and not in, say, the implementations of `ISocketListener` in general and `ISocketListener.OnData()` in particular?

Comment: @greybeard To be fair, you're right. An implementation of the `ISocketListener` does have a bottleneck using `SemaphoreSlim` which limits the processing of that queue. I'll look at refactoring that code. Happy to attach it if you're interested?

Comment: In essence, the `CandleConsolidator` performs a database insert or update and notifies the application of the data change. I'll focus my efforts on optimizing that, most importantly the `sync` logic and the `TODO` comment which I forgot about.

Comment: @AdamH, what is the idea of these listeners? Multiple accounts/api keys?

Comment: @nop it's for handling the data in different ways. for example: Binance api supports one or more socket/s and multiple streams of data, the listeners allowed my to persist one connection and handle data from the different streams in subsequent handlers. i've removed this now and im using reactive observable pattern for the listeners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `SocketOptions`

- `ReceiveBufferSize`/ `SendBufferSize`: They are quite error-prone. For instance the consumer of your utility specifies a negative number. Then it will crash with an `OverflowException`.
- `AutoReconnectAttempts`: you can safely restrict the valid range. Don't need to allow users to specify negative attempt count.

#### `ISocket`

- This interface is a mixture. One group of the methods are related to the Socket. The other half is related to the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)'s `Subject` (register >> `Add`, unregister >> `Remove`). [Interface segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) could help here.

#### `ISocketListener`

- `OnXYZ`: They do seem like they are events but they are not for whatever reason.
- Always be careful when you call user provided code in your context. Image that someone provides an `ISocketListener` with the following implementation:
  `OnConnected(Socket socket) => Thread.Sleep(100*1000);`
- `OnData`: It is really weird for me to use `dynamic` in an interface method. Maybe it is just me.

#### `Socket`

- `Socket` is not really a good name for your class. There is a class with the same name [inside the BCL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?), which resides inside the `System.Net.Sockets` namespace.
- `_listeners`: You should consider to use one of the built-in [Concurrent Collections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent) to avoid locking (`lock(_listeners)`) and copying (`ToArray`) manually.
- `_receive` / `_send`: Even though `Unbounded` channels can [perform better](https://ndportmann.com/system-threading-channels/) than bounded ones, but they can run out of memory.
- `IsConnected`: I don't get it why is this property `public`, or if it is `public` then why is not part of the `ISocket` interface?
- `_endpoint`: It is used without any preliminary checks. `new Uri(_endpoint)` could fail with `UriFormatException` if the provided endpoint is not a valid Url.
- `_wait`: `AutoResetEvent` does have async counterpart ([1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-2-asyncautoresetevent/), [2](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncAutoResetEvent)) it might make sense to make use one of them.
- `OperationCanceledException`: Silently swallowing exceptions (without even logging the fact) is really strange for me. It might make sense to extract the ignorance logic into a separate method to streamline the core logic. [Here is a really good article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Jun/16/Explicitly-Ignoring-Exceptions-in-C) about this topic.
- `Send`: I don't get it why it is synchronous. `TryWrite` has its async counter part `WriteAsync`. Why don't you use that one? (Or `WaitToWriteAsync` ([1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelwriter-1.waittowriteasync)) if you consider to use bounded channels)
- `Dispose`:  `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` is missing.
- `Dispose(bool disposing)`: Your implementation does not use `disposing` parameter. Please check these guidances how to implement Dispose pattern properly ([1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1063), [2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P), [3](https://dzone.com/articles/when-and-how-to-use-dispose-and-finalize-in-c) (more recent article))
- `HandleDataAsync`: Why do you wrap all the functionality into a `Task.Run` and then `await` it? Does it really require to run the whole method on a separate thread?
- `ProcessDataAsync`: Here you are mixing sync and async channel access. Try to use `ReadAsync` instead of `TryRead`. (Or `WaitToReadAsync` ([1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readasync)) if you consider to use bounded channels)
- `_count`: You are increasing and decreasing it manually and then your implementation checks its value against a hard coded limit. Why don't you use bounded channel in the first place?
- `ReceiveAsync`: It might make sense to use `ArrayPool` ([1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1), [2](https://adamsitnik.com/Array-Pool/)) if you could receive quite large data.
- `ReconnectAsync`: It might make sense to use [Polly's retry policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry) to accomplish the retry logic.

---

Unfortunately I could not spend more time to review the consumer side as well. :(

Comment: Very thorough and very much appreciate the links to resources! I'll look to getting through this. Thanks!